# what the meaning displayed value in statistic capture wireshark

Tags: wireshark

i have capture some packet with wireshark, in statistic capture windows there is value named Displayed like this
[image]

then I was figure out that i can count the Capture value (109) from the capure windows, with see the number of row in wireshark capture windows like this
[image]

But how about Displayed value, it is possible to count the value from wireshark capture windows like Captured value? sorry for my english

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two filters in Wireshark: the capture filter (filtered packets are not captured; this actually happens in PCap) and the display filter (filtered packets are not displayed).

In your case `tcp` displays 80 out of 109 captured packets.